# Installing ubuntu on pc with asus motherboard

Tags: system-installation

I want to install ubuntu 16.04. After booting from usb stick and selecting "Install Ubuntu" the screen stays black.

Any ideas, what to do?

---

Edit:

I can boot from  one of the ubuntu advanced options in grub:
 4.4 ubuntu (upstart)

And could figure out the error message:

```
gr: faild to load fecs_inst
```

Comment: What video card, often nomodeset required: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it I had to make many changes to UEFI settings. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2

Comment: Also please precise if you did try "try ubuntu without installing", and if yes, did everything work fine ?

Comment: @oldfred gf-gtx 970 4gb and a gf-gtx 980 4gb